# How to access information in a thread with a timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

I created a form in `C#` where there is a image which is being converted into a boolean array. I am trying to generate a thread with a timer where the image is converted 4 times a second.

When I debug it, it works, I can trace the ticks from the timer. But when the form is running the application quits without giving a bug.

This is the initialize script:

```
form = new LoadForm();
form.Show();
form.BringToFront();

timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(camTick), null, 0, 250);
```

This is the tick that works:

```
private void camTick(Object myObject) 
{
    if (form.isRunning) 
    {
        bool[,] ar = form.getBoolBitmap(100);
    }
}
```

This is the function that loads and saves the bitmap. In form1.cs

```
public bool[,] getBoolBitmap(uint threshold) {
        unsafe {
            Bitmap b = getBitmap();

            BitmapData originalData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            bool[,] ar = new bool[b.Width, b.Height];

            for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++) {
                byte* Row = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);

                for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++) {
                    if ((byte)Row[x * 3] < threshold) {
                        ar[x, y] = false;
                    } else {
                        ar[x, y] = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            b.Dispose();

            return ar;
        }
    }

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        if (!panelVideoPreview.IsDisposed) {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(panelVideoPreview.Width, panelVideoPreview.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
                Rectangle rectanglePanelVideoPreview = panelVideoPreview.Bounds;
                Point sourcePoints = panelVideoPreview.PointToScreen(new Point(panelVideoPreview.ClientRectangle.X, panelVideoPreview.ClientRectangle.Y));
                g.CopyFromScreen(sourcePoints, Point.Empty, rectanglePanelVideoPreview.Size);
            }

            return b;
        } else {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(panelVideoPreview.Width, panelVideoPreview.Height);
            return b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see no evidence this would run 4 times a second.  The event would fire around once every 250ms.  You also need to invoke your control since your trying to modify a control within a Timer thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching on the internet I found this out, I needed to make another function to return the `bool[,]`, this is what I came up with:

```
public bool[,] invokeBitmap(uint treshold) {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {
            return (bool[,])this.Invoke((Func<bool[,]>)delegate {
                return getBoolBitmap(treshold);
            });
        } else {
            return getBoolBitmap(treshold);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you did this then the worker thread would be pointless since nothing useful would be happening on it.

Comment: Mabye I didn't make myself clear...this can't possibly be the right answer. If you did it this way **everything** would be executing on the UI thread. You might as punt on the whole threading idea and call `getBoolBitmap` on the UI thread to begin with. It would be better than doing what you propose here.

Comment: Oh, but it does run pretty smooth now so it's fine.

Comment: Great...then ditch the `System.Threading.Timer` and use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead. That you won't have to use `Invoke` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Is this image being stored in a Control like PictureBox? If so, make sure you're only accessing it on the control's thread. Check out [Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The callback from `System.Threading.Timer` runs on a `ThreadPool` thread. In that callback you are accessing a `Form` instance. You simply cannot do this. Well, you *can*, but it will not work correctly. It will fail unpredictable and sometimes spectacularly.

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead. Have it tick every 4 seconds. In the `Tick` event get whatever data you need from the form and *then* pass it off to another thread for further processing.

In the following code I get the `Bitmap` object by calling `DrawToBitmap` on the UI thread. I then pass the `Bitmap` off to a `Task` where it can be converted into a `bool[]` in the background. Optionally, you can return that `bool[]` from the `Task` and then call `ContinueWith` to transfer it back to the UI thread if necessary (sounds like you probably do not need to do that though).

```
private void YourWindowsFormsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  // Get the bitmap object while still on the UI thread.
  var bm = new Bitmap(panelVideoPreview.ClientSize.Width, panelVideoPreview.ClientSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
  panelVideoPreview.DrawToBitmap(bm, panelVideoPreview.ClientRectangle);

  Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() =>
    {
      // It is not safe to access the UI here.

      bool[,] ar = ConvertBitmapToByteArray(bm);

      DoSomethingWithTheArrayHereIfNecessary(ar);

      // Optionally return the byte array if you need to transfer it to the UI thread.
      return ar;
    })
    .ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
      // It is safe to access the UI here.

      // Get the returned byte array.
      bool[,] ar = task.Result;

      UpdateSomeControlIfNecessaryHere(ar);

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

And `ConvertBitmapToByteArray` would look like this now.

```
public unsafe bool[,] ConvertBitmapToBoolArray(Bitmap b, uint threshold) 
{
  BitmapData originalData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

  bool[,] ar = new bool[b.Width, b.Height];

  for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++) 
  {
    byte* Row = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++) 
    {
      if ((byte)Row[x * 3] < treshold) 
      {
        ar[x, y] = false;
      } else 
      {
        ar[x, y] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  b.Dispose();
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am sorry I don't really understand what you are doing. This is the function where the boolean array is taken, I updated it at the top. It is taken from a picturebox which has a webcam projected on it with Expression Encoder DLL's.

Comment: @ThomasVersteeg: I updated my answer. I think I understand what you are doing now...sorry for the confusion.